# Why is the ratio of components of kinetic energy equal to the ratio of kinetic energy to total energy for a projectile whose range is maximized?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, kinematics, projectile

The launch angle $\theta$ that maximizes the range of a projectile in a uniform gravitational field is

\begin{align}
\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{v_o}{\sqrt{v_o^2 + 2gh}}\right), \tag{1}
\end{align}

for an initial height $h$ and initial velocity $v_o$. This angle is typically found by the usual methods of calculus (ie. differentiating the range w.r.t. $\theta$).   Equivalently, the angle $\theta$ satisfies

\begin{equation}
\tan^2(\theta) = \frac{v_o^2}{v_o^2 + 2gh}. \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Multiplying the r.h.s. by factors of 1/2 and mass $m$, we find

\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{1}{2}mv_o^2}{\frac{1}{2}mv_o^2 + mgh} = \frac{K}{E}, \tag{3}
\end{equation}

where $K$ is the kinetic energy and $E = K + V$ is the total energy. The l.h.s. is also equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\tan^2(\theta) = \frac{\frac{1}{2}mv_{oy}^2}{\frac{1}{2}mv_{ox}^2} = \frac{K_y}{K_x} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

which leads to an interesting equality between the ratios of these energies

\begin{equation}
\frac{K_y}{K_x} = \frac{K}{E}, \tag{5}
\end{equation}
when the range of the projectile is maximized. I haven't been able to find a good argument for why these ratios would be equivalent, so I thought I'd ask Physics SE. What accounts for this equality?

If nothing else, it serves as a neat mental shorthand for getting to the optimal angle quickly. The brute force calculus method is tedious, but this equality suggests there may be a neat physical argument that is relatively painless. How can I develop an intuition for (5)?

Comment: Since kinetic energy is a scalar quantity we don't usually talk about its components? Still, good observation

Comment: Agreed that the language I used is weird. Had difficulty trying to express those terms succinctly.

Comment: That's a neat observation. It feels a bit like a fluke? But it's too clean to rule out a simple explanation. I hope it clicks for someone (or it's out there already).

Comment: equation (4) is just trigonometry  with $~v_{0x}=v_0\,\cos(\theta)~,v_{0y}=v_0\,\sin(\theta)~$

so the question is why equation (3) is valid ?

Comment: Equation (3) should be valid just by the definition of kinetic and potential energy. Here’s another way to phrase my original question. In my “derivation,” I took the path (1)->(5) because we know (1) is true from calculus. I’d like to know if there’s a way to independently establish (5) as true so that we can instead take the path (5)->(1) to deduce the optimal launch angle. As @EmilioPisanty points out, it could be a fluke/coincidence in which case we couldn’t establish (5) independently of (1). I’m hopeful there’s something deeper here though.